# Some problems with creating a button and binding an event handler

Tags: javascript

```
(function(){
  company = {
    name: 'Jalconsmile',
    welcome: function(){
      alert('Welcome to ' + name);
    }
  };
  button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHtml = 'Come to us';
  button.addEventListener('click', company.welcome);
  document.body.appendChild(button);
})();
```

This code not working, can someone help me? I tried all what I know.

Comment: Works fine. Just replace innerHtml with innerHTML.

Comment: There are multiple problems. The `.innerHtml` capitalization is one. Another is that you're passing the `welcome` function without the `company` object. Even with that corrected, the `name` will not be the one you're trying to get. You're also creating two global variables, which isn't great.

Comment: @squint: Good catch. Did not even realize this one at first.

Comment: *In what way* is it not working? We can't exactly help you unless you tell us what you expected and what you got.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe this should work.

```js
(function() {
    company = {
        name: 'Jalconsmile',
        welcome: function() {
            alert('Welcome to ' + company.name);
        }
    };
    button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerHTML = 'Come to us';
    button.addEventListener('click', company.welcome);
    document.body.appendChild(button);
})();
```

Comment: why when is press button i got "Welcome to result"? or it's problem in my side?

Comment: The button is associated with the function welcome `button.addEventListener('click', company.welcome);`

Comment: I changed the `alert` function call to show the name correctly.

Answer (score 2):

So there are two main problems:

1. innerHtml should be innerHTML (case sensitive)

   > button.innerHTML= 'Come to us';
2. '+ name' should be '+ company.name' (scope)

   > alert('Welcome to ' + company.name);
3. Additionally declare button locally (not a must but..)

   > var button = document.createElement('button');

Also regards to squint for pointing out the name-scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

you mistyped innerHTML. check the cases. javascript is case sensitive. you type innerHtml instead of HTML

```
(function(){
company = {
name: 'Jalconsmile',
welcome: function(){
alert('Welcome to ' + name);
}
};
button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = 'Come to us';
button.addEventListener('click', company.welcome);
document.body.appendChild(button);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks normal except `button.innerHtml = 'Come to us';`

it should be `button.innerHTML = 'Come to us';` instead.

So pretty much it should look like this:

```
(function(){
company = {
name: 'Jalconsmile',
welcome: function(){
alert('Welcome to ' + name);
}
};
button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = 'Come to us';
button.addEventListener('click', company.welcome);
document.body.appendChild(button);
})();
```